# What is the origin of the Qin Shi Huang theme music in Civilization IV?

Tags: civilization-4, game-music-identification

I've been trying to identify the music that is heard while one talks diplomacy with *Qin Shi Huang* in *Civilization IV*. The melody has been stuck in my head for a while now, and I'd like to know what it is I keep whistling.

Sadly, it's not listed on [the Wikipedia article about music in *Civilization IV*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_in_Civilization_IV).

Since I have not played any other games in the series, it is entirely possible the theme is a remake of music from an older game in the *Civilization* series.

Does anyone know more about this music theme?

For reference: I'm talking about this song:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an arrangement of the title theme to the Super NES conversion of the original *Civilization*.

[If this link doesn't work I'm sure you can find it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FJ5v0acZkk)

Answer (score 0):

I believe thats an original track for civilization 4. It's not based on an existing song as I didn't find any references to any track on album. But to be sure I would simply send an email to the game support team and I think they could confirm this.

As for the music the game already has you could just download that youtube video and extract the sound. Alternatively, if you want I can get the game from a friend and try to locate/rip the track for you.

However, I think you can find music similar to the this one easily. Just search for Chinese classical music on youtube.